# Swipe between two WebViews

Tags: android, webview, swipe

I was trying to display two `WebView`s in only one page, but finally I realized that it's quite ugly, so I was wondering if there is a way to swipe between these two `WebView`s, and if so, how to code it.

Here is my old code (two `WebView`s in one page)

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      


        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Webview1);
        WebView webView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Webview2);

        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView2.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView2.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);


        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        webView2.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        webView2.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/BarChart.html");
        webView2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/PieChart.html");
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `ViewPager`? But you may have problems if you still want to scroll horizontally within the Webview. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: well right now i am following this tutorial (http://www.lucazanini.eu/2013/android/how-to-restore-the-state-of-w-webview-in-a-layout-tabs-swipe-with-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter/?lang=en) but i'm not sure it fits with my problem

Comment: I would first try the ViewPager alone (http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) and if it works for you, you can try to save the state.

Comment: alright now i when i try to build the projet it sends me this "Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager"
PS : i am using android studio

Comment: Sorry, i can't help you with Android Studio, but it sounds like you haven't included the support-library in your project

Answer (score 0):

To swipe between two webviews your going to need custom webviews because a webview does not have swipe functionality by default and change between the two of them.  The following code does this very well.  Version change, added code for top and bottom swipe functionality also.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyWebView webView1;
    MyWebView webView2;

    LinearLayout ll1;
    LinearLayout ll2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConstraintLayout parentLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentlayout);

        Button b1 = new Button(this);
        b1.setText("Mobile");
        b1.setWidth(140);
        Button b2 = new Button(this);
        b2.setText("Web");
        b2.setWidth(140);

        LinearLayout linearlayout1 = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 140);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                450, 140);

        linearlayout1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        linearlayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearlayout1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP);
        linearlayout1.addView(b1, buttonParams);
        linearlayout1.addView(b2, buttonParams);

        ll1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll2 = new LinearLayout(this);

        webView1 = new MyWebView(this);
        webView2 = new MyWebView(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        parentLayout.addView(linearlayout1);

        parentLayout.addView(ll1, layoutParams1);
        parentLayout.addView(ll2, layoutParams1);

        ll1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ll2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        layoutParams2.setMargins(30, 150, 30, 0);

        ll1.addView(webView1, layoutParams2);
        ll2.addView(webView2, layoutParams2);

        webView1.setInitialScale(1);
        webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView1.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView1.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView1.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView1.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView1.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView1.loadUrl("http://example.com");


        webView2.setInitialScale(1);
        webView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView2.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView2.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView2.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView2.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView2.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView2.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView2.loadUrl("https://bestinternetsearch.com");

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        // mobile view
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something in response to button click
                ll1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ll2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                show_toast("button1");
            }
        });

        // web view
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something in response to button click
                ll1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ll2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                show_toast("button2");
            }
        });

    }

    void show_toast(final String text) {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    }


    class MyWebView extends WebView {
        Context context;
        GestureDetector gd;
        MyWebView mywebview;

        private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        public MyWebView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.context = context;
            gd = new GestureDetector(context, sogl);
            mywebview = this;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            gd.onTouchEvent(event);
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener sogl = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();

                if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (distanceX > 0) {
                            //mywebview.goForward();
                            //show_toast("swipe right");
                            ll1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            ll2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            //mywebview.goBack();
                            //show_toast("swipe left");
                            ll1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            ll2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else if (Math.abs(distanceY) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (distanceY > 0) {
                        show_toast("swipe bottom");
                        //onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        show_toast("swipe top");
                        //onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        };

        void show_toast(final String text) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }


    }


    //@Override
    //public void onBackPressed() {  // navigation bar
        //webview.goBack();
        //super.onBackPressed();
    //}

}
```